# How to print only strings from an array containing different data types in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have:

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", 9];
let text = fruits.toString();
console.log(text)
```

It prints the entire array but I only want to print the string elements of the array and exclude 9, how can I do that?

Result - Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango, 9

Desired result - Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango

Comment: Did you really expect a function whose purpose is to convert anything to a string to filter out non-strings?

Comment: @Barmar no, I did not know about the typeof operator. Thanks for the answer BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango",9];
let text = fruits.filter(f => typeof (f) === 'string').toString();
console.log(text)
```

The `typeof` operator can be used to determine the data type of each object.

The `filter` can be used to filter out only those elements that satisfies the given condition or predicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to get the results

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", 9];

let text = fruits.filter(r => typeof(r) === "string");

console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter the items (using the `filter` function) whose type is a string (using `typeof` operator).

```
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango",9];
// filter the string data type items
let text = fruits.filter(item => typeof item === "string").toString();
console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", 9]
.filter(text => typeof(text) === "string").toString();
    
    console.log(fruits)
```